# Want to see a singular variety such that its sheaf of relative differentials IS locally free.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne Chap II Thm 8.17 says

suppose $X$ is nonsingular, $Y\subset X$ be an irreducible and closed subscheme defined by an ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$. Then $Y$ is nonsingular if and only if :

(1)$\Omega_{Y/k}$ is locally free, and

(2) $0\rightarrow\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I^2}\rightarrow \Omega_{X/k}\rightarrow \Omega_{Y/k}\rightarrow 0 $ is exact.

I would like to see an example such that Y is singular but $\Omega_{Y/k}$ is still locally free.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, your second sequence is not correct. The middle term should be $\Omega_{X/k}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_Y$.

For an example, take $X=\mathbb{A}^1_k=\mathrm{Spec} k[x]$, $k$ a field of characteristic 2 (for definiteness) and let $Y$ be defined by $x^2=0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But do you mean char k is NOT 2 ?

Comment: No, I meant char 2. You can take $x^p=0$ in char p.